# Finding possible values of $L_x$ given $L^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, representation-theory

Here's a homework problem I'm working on. I am not asking for the answer, but any guidance or comments on the approach are appreciated.

> Given that a measurement of $L^2$ for a free particle has resulted in the value $6\hbar^2$, what are the possible results for a measurement of $L_x$?

I've been following the approach given on pp. 378-380 in Liboff (4th ed.). I've made it as far as expressing the eigenfunctions of $L_x$ as sums of the eigenfunctions of $L^2$... Here's what I've got:

$$\begin{align*}
X_1 &= \frac{1}{2}\left(|2,2\rangle - |2,1\rangle + |2,-1\rangle - |2,-2\rangle\right)\\
X_2 = -X1 &= -\frac{1}{2}\left(|2,2\rangle - |2,1\rangle + |2,-1\rangle - |2,-2\rangle\right)\\
X_3 &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}|2,2\rangle - |2,0\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}|2,-2\rangle\right)\\
X_4 = -X3 &= -\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}|2,2\rangle - |2,0\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}|2,-2\rangle\right)\\
X_5 &= \frac{1}{2}(|2,2\rangle + |2,1\rangle - |2,-1\rangle - |2,-2\rangle)\\
X_6 = -X_5 &= -\frac{1}{2}\left(|2,2\rangle + |2,1\rangle - |2,-1\rangle - |2,-2\rangle\right)
\end{align*}$$

The next step appears to be to express $L^2$ as sums of the eigenfunctions of $L_x$, which does not seem possible.

It was a lot of algebra, matrices, determinants, etc. to get to this point so it is certainly possible that I've miscalculated something accidentally, but does anyone see anything fundamentally wrong here with this approach? And/or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Well, it looks like my list of eigenfunctions of Lx came through as an unreadable mess.

Comment: Sandwich your formulas between `$` signs for in-line TeX formatting. Using double signs (`$$`) will make the formula take its own line. Alternatively, add an extra blank line to force a new line in the output. (all this is also explained on the 'ASK QUESTION' page, in the right sidebar)

Comment: Hey, now it looks great...thanks!!! I will make a note for future questions/responses.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `$$\begin{eqnarray} eq1 \\ eq2 \\ ... \\ eqn \end{eqnarray}$$` and have your equations aligned.

Comment: @KyleKanos Actually, `eqnarray` is outdated and it's better to use `align`.

Comment: For completeness, syntax is `$$\begin{align} leq1 &= req1 \\ leq2 &= req2 \\ ... \\ leqn &= reqn \end{align}$$`. It actually wouldn't surprise me if MathJax internally implements `eqnarray` as a variant of `align`, so maybe it doesn't matter so much here, but in real LaTeX `eqnarray` is definitely deprecated.

Comment: Oh, and is this question about a hydrogen atom? That would be important to mention.

Comment: @Wouter: completely unawares of deprecation of `eqnarray`. Is that something that happened like 10 years ago and no one told me?

Comment: If $X_2 = -X_1$, then they are physically the same eigenstate, since they different only by a global phase factor. Also, see @DavidZ's comment.

Comment: $L^2$ has a dimension of $\hbar^2$, so you have an error in the formulation of the problem.

Comment: I may be missing something, but from the problem setup, (which I assume you mean $\hat{L}^2=6\hbar^2$), then quantum number $l=2$. The operator $\hat{L}_x$ can yield the value $-l\hbar$ to $+l\hbar$ in integer steps. I don't there's enough information to specify which of these five are or aren't possible for the problem unless you give more info.

Comment: @KyleKanos I actually have no idea. It's something I only found out about myself two years or so ago.

Comment: Ah yes, I did mean $6\hbar^2$. And this is for a "free particle", not the hydrogen atom.

Comment: BMS, you say that $L_x$ can yield the value $−lℏ$ to $+lℏ$ in integer steps. Should that be an obvious result? It is not clear to me.

Comment: Thanks, Stan, for your comment regarding $X_2=-X_1$. I did not realize that. It's probably obvious, but I'm not quite comfortable playing in the world of operators, eigenstates, etc.

Comment: @RamblinWreck: I have 2nd Edition of Liboff, but he discusses that $m\in(-l,\,l)$ by integer steps in Section 9.2, it'll probably be around there that this is mentioned in your newer edition.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. I see in Liboff where he goes through and shows that eigenvalues for $L_z$ are integral steps of $\hbar$ from $-l\hbar$ to $+l\hbar$. Perhaps the same eigenvalues result for $L_x$, but if so it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

If $L^2$ is $6\hslash^2$ this means that the quantum number $l$ is $2$, hence the quantum number $m$ goes from $-2$ to $+2$, and the possible values of $L_x$ are $-2\hslash, -\hslash, 0, \hslash, 2\hslash$

Conventionally $L_z$ is used instead than $L_x$, but what applies to $L_z$ must apply also to $L_x$ and $L_y$: there are no preferential directions in space.

Comment: Thanks, MiMo. I understand why the possible values of $L_z$ are $-2\hbar, -\hbar, 0, \hbar, 2\hbar$, and Liboff does a good job explaining this in his text. It looks like I am going to have to convince myself why this is also the case for $L_x$...and presumably $L_y$.

Comment: There are no preferential direction in space, what applies to one axis must apply to the others...

Answer (score 1):

Since the operator $L^2$ yielded $6\hbar^2$, one can deduce that $l=2$ after measurement. In general, the *only possible measurements* of one of the $L_i$ components are from $-l\hbar$ to $+l\hbar$ in integer steps. If you're comfortable with this for $L_Z$, note that none of the angular momentum operators $L_i$ are fundamentally more special than the other two, so the same will be true for $L_x$. Based on the (lack of) information given in the problem, I don't think there's enough to say anything more than this. Perhaps if we knew what was done prior to to the $L^2$ measurement we could say more.